# How do they write different language wrappers for same library?

Tags: language-agnostic

Generally a library will be released in a single language (for example C). If the library tuns out to be useful then many language wrappers for that library will be written. How *exactly* do they do it?

Kindly someone throw little light on this topic. If it is too language dependent pick language of your choice and explain it.

Comment: a related read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636841/how-do-multiple-languages-interact-in-one-project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options that come to mind:

- Port the original C library to the language/platform of your choice
- Compile the C library into something (like a DLL) that can be invoked from other components
- Put the library on the web, expose an API over HTTP and wrap that on the client

If I wanted to wrap a C library with a managed (.NET) layer, I'd compile the library into a DLL, exposing the APIs I wanted. Then, I'd use P/Invoke to call those APIs from my C# code.

Comment: What is the Java domain equivalent of P/Invoke in .NET

Comment: What about interpreted languages like perl/python/php?

Comment: @claws: JNI is the most common.

Comment: @claws: There are two common strategies for Python: Boost::Python and SWIG (which also supports PHP, Perl and Java).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: thanks. I'll try them myself. But, I asked this question from learning point of view. So, could you kindly explain how these SWIG or Boost::Python work to provide wrappers? I want to know about the layer at which these two different languages communicate.

Comment: @Jim Lamb: Are these only ways? What other ways do they have?

Comment: @claws: SWIG's interface with Python is explained here (to at least some degree): http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html.